# How to upload images to magic 360 extension by script

Tags: magento-1.9

I installed `magic 360 extension` which is working fine but I have difficulty to upload images for 10,000 products, here I want script to upload images based on product SKU,

**Exampe:** SKU Images P1001 36 P2002 36 P3003 38

Answer (score 0):

To bulk upload many images to your Magento site, use one of the 2 scripts that comes with Magic 360 extension.

1. Upload your images to your Magento site using FTP. The location and folder structure must follow one of these two patterns.

Either:

```
https://yourdomain.com/Magic/**{product-SKU}**/360/anyfilename1.jpg
https://yourdomain.com/Magic/**{product-SKU}**/360/anyfilename2.jpg
https://yourdomain.com/Magic/**{product-SKU}**/360/anyfilename3.jpg
etc.
```

or:

```
https://yourdomain.com/Magic_id/**{product-ID}**/360/anyfilename1.jpg
https://yourdomain.com/Magic_id/**{product-ID}**/360/anyfilename2.jpg
https://yourdomain.com/Magic_id/**{product-ID}**/360/anyfilename3.jpg
etc.
```

The folder names must exactly match your product ID or SKU. The file names can be anything - images will be added to the spin in alphanumeric order.

2. Download the latest version of [Magic 360 for Magento](https://www.magictoolbox.com/magic360/modules/magento/).
3. Unzip the extension.
4. Find these two bulk upload scripts:

   **bulk_360.php**

   **bulk_360_id.php**
5. Upload those two scripts to the root of your Magento site e.g.

https:// yourdomain.com/bulk_360.php

https:// yourdomain.com/bulk_360_id.php

6. Execute the script that matches your folder names. The bulk_360.php script is for folders named with the product SKU. The bulk_360_id.php script is for folders named with the product ID.

All the images will be copied to the Magento database. Once complete, the script will show you a list of successful results.

As you're going to upload 10,000 products, it may take up to 2 hours, depending on the file size and number of images in your 360 spins.

You can safely delete the images which were successuflly imported. You can run the script again to import any images which failed.

Comment: I did modification as per suggested even this code not importing images based on product_id pls help

Comment: If you've followed the mass image upload instructions here:

https://www.magictoolbox.com/magic360/modules/magento/#bulk-upload-images

and it is not working, then contact the Magic Toolbox technical support team:

https://magictoolbox.com/contact/